# Freeradius problem reading google_authenticator secrets Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, root, freeradius, google-authenticator

I have a `freeradius` server setup with google `authenticator` to provide a basic working multi-factor setup.

Everything works when I run `radiusd` in debug mode as root.  If I start it as a service, logons fail and this messages is recorded when processing messages:

radiusd(pam_google_authenticator)[1115]: Failed to read "/home/user@domain.com/.google_authenticator" for "user@domain.com"

I think this must be a permissions issue since it works fine when run as `root`.

I don't really want to edit the permissions on each secret file for every user.

I have tried specifying root in

> /etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
>
> user = root group = root

but still the service fails unless run from the command line as root.  Does anyone have a nice elegant solution to this conundrum?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check out your systemd service file for `radiusd`. It might look something like:

https://github.com/ipfire/ipfire-3.x/blob/master/freeradius/systemd/freeradius.service

You can add `User=` and `Group=` in the `[Service]` section of the `.service` file if needed.  See

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347358/how-to-change-service-user-in-centos-7

and

https://serverfault.com/questions/806617/configuring-systemd-service-to-run-with-root-access

It would be a good idea to put the contents of the `.service` file for `radiusd` in your post.

Comment: [Unit]  
Description=FreeRADIUS high performance RADIUS server.  
After=syslog.target network.target ipa.service dirsrv.target krb5kdc.service  
  
[Service]  
User=root  
Group=root  
Type=forking  
PIDFile=/var/run/radiusd/radiusd.pid  
ExecStartPre=-/bin/chown -R radiusd.radiusd /var/run/radiusd  
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/radiusd -C  
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/radiusd -d /etc/raddb  
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/radiusd -C  
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID  
  
[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target  
  
But the error remains.